# Will std::queue front take front element out of the line?

Tags: c++, queue, std

Will `std::queue::front` take front element out of the line? And if not how to delete it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a function for getting the element, another for deleting it:

```
typedef queue<MyClass> MyQueue;
MyQueue q;
q.push(MyClass(42));
// ...
MyClass const& rx = q.front();
rx.print();

MyClass x = q.front(); // Copies the front element to a fresh object
q.pop(); // From this point, rx is a dangling reference
assert(x == MyClass(42));
```

Rationale: if there were only one `pop` function which returns the front element, it wouldn't be possible to get a reference to the front element, since it would have been removed from the queue. If you just want to read a huge element before discarding it, you surely don't want your code to perform a copy.

EDIT: One more fundamental reason is that having two functions means that the user is responsible for making the copy. Assume there is only one single `pop` function: what would happen if the copy constructor (inside `pop`) throws an exception ? (cf. @Steve Jessop 's comment)

Comment: ... and even if you did want to make a copy, there is no way to return by value while providing a strong exception guarantee. The copy to the caller's lvalue takes place *after* the object has been removed from the queue, so if the copy ctor or copy assignment (whichever it is in that specific case) throws an exception, the queue has already been popped.

Comment: @Steve: you're right. To be complete, one should mention exception safety.

Comment: @Alexandre: as underlined by Steve, the rationale is about exception guarantees, not about `interface` since you could have both `front` and a `pop` that returns a copy. It was either this behavior, or requiring that copy constructors may not throw.

Comment: @Matthieu: One could have required that if the copy constructor throws, the queue is left in the state it was before the construction attempt. This would have required some extended form of RVO, or two copies.

Comment: @Alexandre C. Two copies wouldn't do it. It would have to be by mandating not only RVO, but also a form of RVO which allows a *copy-assignment* to be in-place, not just a copy construction, to make `MyClass x; x = q.pop();` exception-safe. It's just not doable in C++ as we know it. A far simpler alternative would be for `pop` to take a non-const reference parameter, and copy the front object into that before modifying the queue. That could then easily be exception-safe, and AFAIK the reason it isn't offered is just that it's a trivial combination of `front()` and `pop()`, so DIY.

Comment: @Alexandre: actually, this could be done with another interface `queue.pop(item)`, using assignment instead of copy construction. This is less idiomatic I guess.

Answer (score 2):

No, it just returns a reference to the front element. If you need to take out the element use `pop()`. See [std::queue](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/queue.html#3) reference for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Type definitions of the front operation for queue.

```
value_type& queue::front ()
const value_type& queue::front () const
```

Both forms return next element of the queue. The caller has to ensure that the queue contains an element (size()>0); otherwise, the behavior is undefined. The first form for nonconstant queues returns a reference. Thus, you could modify the next element while it is in the queue. It is up to you to decide whether this is good style.

Use pop to delete it. It removes the next element from the queue. The next element is the element that was inserted first (before all other elements in the queue). This function has no return value. To process the next element, you must call front() first.